# Looking for a way or a plugin that save my marked text and could restore it after loose of focus

Tags: text, range, selected, rangy

like i menthioned in the topic i'm looking for a plugin that save my marked text and could restore it after loose of focus. Like a JS Library called Rangy i used in the past. Is there such a plugin or does anyone has an idea how i could deal with this kind of problem?

Regardings Adrian

```
function gEBI(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
}

var savedSel;
var savedSelActiveElement;

function saveSelection() {

    if (savedSel) {
      //  rangy.removeMarkers(savedSel);
    }
    savedSel = rangy.saveSelection();
    savedSelActiveElement = document.activeElement;

}

function restoreSelection() {
    if (savedSel) {
        rangy.restoreSelection(savedSel, true);

        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (savedSelActiveElement && typeof savedSelActiveElement.focus != "undefined") {
                savedSelActiveElement.focus();
            }
        }, 1);
    }
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    try {
        document.execCommand("MultipleSelection", null, true);
    } catch(ex) {}
    rangy.init();

     // Enable buttons
    var saveRestoreModule = rangy.modules.SaveRestore;
    if (rangy.supported && saveRestoreModule && saveRestoreModule.supported) {

        var saveButton = gEBI("saveButton");
        //saveButton.disabled = false;
        saveButton.ontouchstart = saveButton.onmousedown = function() {
            saveSelection();
            return false;
        };

        $('.EditorTab').mousedown(function(){
            saveSelection();
            return false;
        });
});
```

Comment: So what's wrong with Rangy? Don't worry, you're unlikely to hurt my feelings :)

Comment: Nothing's wrong with! New day, new thoughts :D 
I just need to find a way how i can keep my selection longer than one restore. I'm trying to combine rangy with jquery ui tabs. I fire the save method when clicking on a tab and restoring the selection if i click on one option in the tab. In the tabs are some text formating tools and i dont want to loose the selection if click on lets say different colors.

BTW i love rangy and trust me i will keep using it!

Answer (score 0):

The following solution would allow you to store and restore any number of ranges, but it assumes that you have not destroyed the nodes that the ranges are attached to when it comes time to restore those ranges.

```
var SelectionStore = (function() {

    var savedRanges = {};

    return {

        store: function(saveIdentifier) {
            var ranges = rangy.getSelection().getAllRanges();
            savedRanges[saveIdentifier] = ranges;
            return ranges;
        },

        restore: function(saveIdentifier) {
            var i, selection;
            selection = rangy.getSelection();
            if (!savedRanges[saveIdentifier]) throw new Error('Invalid saved selection identifier used. Selection not found for ID: ' + saveIdentifier);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            for (i in savedRanges[saveIdentifier]) selection.addRange(savedRanges[saveIdentifier][i]);
        }

    }

})();
```

Usage examples:

```
//store the current selection
SelectionStore.store('Tab1');

//restore a selection
SelectionStore.restore('Tab1');
```